# How to fix ' list indices must be integers or slices, not list' error?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, indexing

I am trying to study numpy and I just learned fancy indexing and argsort. In order to get used to these two, i wrote simple code and I keep getting the error

```
'TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not list'
```

What is causing this?

```
import numpy as np
array = ['John','Mike','Sarah','Kate','Samuel']
score_array = [78, 95, 84, 98, 88]
idx = np.argsort(score_array)
idx = idx.tolist()
array[idx]
```

Comment: You are trying to use a numpy array to index a regular list. Perhaps you meant to convert your lists to `np.array`?

Comment: Just because something is called `array` does not mean it accepts `numpy` array style indexing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure what you want to do. If you convert the two lists to numpy arrays. It runs without error.

```
import numpy as np

array = np.array(['John','Mike','Sarah','Kate','Samuel'])
score_array = np.array([78, 95, 84, 98, 88])
idx = np.argsort(score_array)
idx = idx.tolist()
print(array[idx])
```

Because `array` is now a numpy array it accepts the array style indexing.

Comment: oh it should be numpy array! I made mistake at that part. I am so appreciated for your help.

Comment: Cool. You can accept the answer if you want, by clicking the green tick to the left of the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You're converting idx to a list and trying to access another list with it.

Lists are accessed with a number index, and since you're using a list python is giving you a type error.

`print(array[some_number])` or `print(array)`